# PulseAudio naming a device

Tags: pulseaudio

I found the Question and answer:

[How can I use PulseAudio virtual audio streams to play music over Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/q/257992/85695)

I am currently using the command

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1
```

to create my virtual devices. But would like to use

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1 sink_properties=device.description="NAME HERE (mic+music)"
```

But when issuing the command, I get the following error.

```
$ pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual2 sink_properties=device.description="NAME HERE (only music)"
Failure: Module initialization failed
```

Is there another way to name the device? Whilst making a virtual device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no documentation to the effect but it looks like you need to create the sink first then assign it properties.

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MySink
pacmd update-sink-proplist MySink device.description=MySink
```

To add a `device.description` with spaces please use the format "single-quotes"-"double-quotes"-"label".

```
pacmd load-module module-null-sink sink_name=MySink
pacmd update-sink-proplist MySink device.description='"My Sink"'
```

Comment: I've noticed a bug when using spaces in the description: "Failed to parse proplist."

Comment: Thank you! :-) You can play with `pacmd` in the first place to see the results live without restarting the daemon / local service. When you want to make this loaded by PulseAudio as default put these commands in `default.pa` configuration file (without `pacmd`).

Comment: @CeDeROM if you use `update-sink-proplist` you do not need double quoting in `default.pa`.

Comment: Here is a related answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417190/111181

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1 sink_properties="'device.description=\"NAME HERE (mic+music)\"'"
```

To make the same setting in `default.pa` file use line:

```
load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1 sink_properties='device.description="NAME HERE (mic+music)"'
```

These work at least by pulseaudio 13.99.1.

Comment: If you have more than one property to set, you could just add them similarly separated by space within the outermost quotes.