# Change what PulseAudio calls a device?

Tags: audio, alsa, pulseaudio

I use a headset for both my headphones and my microphone. As a result `pavucontrol` is labeling both my output and my input the same thing, `Built-in Audio Analogue Stereo`. It makes configuring my loopback-modules somewhat frustrating for obvious reasons. How would I go about just renaming them to "Headphones" and "Mic"?

Comment: I'm confused why it makes configureing your loopback modules difficult. In `pavucontrol`, you always distinguish between `Playback` and `Record`, so you know which is which. From the commandline, the interal names are different, they start e.g. with `alsa_output` or `alsa_input`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can update the `device.description` with `update-sink-proplist` and `update-source-proplist`, e.g.

> pacmd update-sink-proplist alsa_output.my-card.analog-stereo device.description=MyCard

I haven't figured out how to make that parse spaces in the name properly.

Comment: That solved it, thanks. Just want to add for anybody who reads this later, there's a nifty GUI tool called `paman` that will tell you what the ALSA identification for each device is.

Comment: @DaviMedrade And no, just adding quotes doesn't make ALSA parse the spaces correctly. It just makes the shell parse the spaces (but that is obvious). You really need double quoting as in the other answer.

Answer (score 14):

To improve upon [dirkt's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316098/248579), due to the way shell arguments are interpreted, spaces in PulseAudio properties such as the description require double quoting:

```
pacmd 'update-sink-proplist alsa_output.my-card.analog-stereo device.description="My Card" '
```

To run a command automatically on every login, you can append it to your PulseAudio startup script (usually `~/.config/pulse/default.pa` or `~/.pulse/default.pa`), without `pacmd` and the extra quotes.

If you don't know the name of the device you're looking for, this is the quickest way to see lists of output sinks and input sources:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
pacmd list-sources | grep name:
```

Comment: Is there a way to rename Card properties in addition to Sink properties?

Comment: @JasonSiefken, can you provide an example? Sounds like low-level stuff that'd need system-wide changes.

Comment: I am trying to get the device name to change in `gnome-settings`. It appears that it uses the Card's property `device.description`, not the Source/Sink's property. However, there doesn't appear to be a `update-card-proplist` command...

Comment: I think it's best if you create a new question with a reference to this one, as this comment space is too limited to discuss all the details involved. Check out "man pulse-cli-syntax" and "pacmd info | less" for starters. You might spot some useful commands and fields in them.