# Changing the device description of a card

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa

I added a `snd_aloop` device to my setup and PulseAudio automatically picked it up and lists it as "Audio interne" (see eg. `pavucontrol`'s Configuration tab), the same as my regular sound card, which makes it difficult to understand things.

[This question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316067/change-what-pulseaudio-calls-a-device) is similarly titled but they are in fact dealing with the name of the sources and sinks, which I was able to change to suit my needs. But I want to change the name of the card itself as well because some applications refer to it directly instead of the sinks/sources.

However, while I can get the `device.description` of the card with `pacmd list-cards`, I could not find an equivalent `pacmd update-card-proplist` to change it.

Maybe this is set in alsa rather than pulseaudio ? The device is listed as `Loopback` in `/proc/asound/`, a name that would suit my needs.

The card name is localised into French, so I assume it is not a built-in default. I text-searched for that string in /usr/ and /etc/, to no avail. I do not know whence the system gets this name.

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you need an ALSA `snd_aloop`, when Pulseaudio offers the same functionality in-built without all the drawbacks of the ALSA device? And if you use Pulseaudio functionality and load the modules explicitely, it's also a lot easier to set names and descriptions...

Answer (score 2):

I checked pulseaudio source code and found that the card name as showed on pavucontrol configuration tab comes from an attribute named "ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE" that you can set via udev rules. For example, to set a specific name to any USB audio card connected to a given USB port:

`/etc/udev/rules.d/85-identify-usb-sound-cards.rules`:

```
SUBSYSTEM!="sound", GOTO="pa_naming_end"
ACTION!="change", GOTO="pa_naming_end"
KERNEL!="card*", GOTO="pa_naming_end"

DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.2/3-1.2:1.0/sound/card?", ENV{ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE}="FT-2900 Audio"

LABEL="pa_naming_end"
```

The result (my setup involves several USB audio interfaces):
[image: pavucontrol configuration tab]

Answer (score 0):

device names can be changed in Pulseaudio (`pavucontrol`) if Pulseaudio has module-device manager loaded

check if module is already loaded - `pactl list short modules | grep device-manager`

if it needs to be added - `pactl load-module module-device-manager`

if module-manager is loaded can right-click on the 'Port:' dropdown menu to rename the device

[image]

Comment: Thanks but this is renaming the sink or source, which I have already done. I am trying to rename the virtual sound card as would appear in the Configuration tab.

Comment: question did not mention having already tried this. this is simplest way i know to change input/output device descriptions. can also load sinks/sources statically by reconfiguring default.pa modules and name can be assigned - no card is visible in Configuration tab using that method. may be possible to statically load a whole card to set the name but i never got it to work. did not see much point in trying to use udev rules or other changes to adjust Configuration tab display when i rarely use it compared to other pavucontrol tabs

Comment: WOW thank you so much, I was having issues since I have two things named the exact same but one doesn't work, and it was a game of trial and error for video conferences. This seems like something that should have much more intuitive interface! I tried right clicking on the name, double clicking name, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some kind of solution : delete the existing sink/card, then recreate a new one with a choosen name ...

1. Delete the sink/card :  by unloading the module (get module used by the sink/device name):

`$ pactl list sinks`

Name: ...

Description: ...

Owner Module: 19 <-- HERE

2. Then, to "delete" (disable) such sink, by unload that module :

`$ pactl unload-module 19`

3. Get the cards's name :

`$ pacmd list-cards`

4. Create the new sink:

`$ pacmd load-module module-remap-sink master=[card-NAME] channels=2 channel_map=front-left,front-right sink_name=[SOME-sink-NAME]  sink_properties=device.description=[SOME-NAME-pavucontrol]`